# Can I remove things on a map

Tags: google-maps

I've never used the google maps api before, just wondering if I could remove everything on a map except the country borders. I also want the country names and city names only left on my map. No color, no contour lines, no elevation lines, nothing except these. Also, would I be able to set up reference points so that I could write a program to highlight an area (and then control its brightness or color or size of highlighted area dynamically at runtime based on some external input for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of your question (removing things from the standard maps), what you're looking for is the [Styled Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling) feature in the Maps API.

To explore what the different styling options do, use the [Styled Maps Wizard](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html). When you get the style you want, click the Show JSON button to get the data that you can plug into the API.

The user interface of the Styled Maps Wizard is a little confusing. Be sure to read the help panel and keep experimenting with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can [read a KML file](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_us_states_kml_test.html) to show the outline of a state or country. [Data layers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer) can also be used to add custom content such as markers to a map.

Valid stock [map types](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes) are:

- `MapTypeId.ROADMAP` to displays the default road map view.
- `MapTypeId.SATELLITE` to displays Google Earth satellite
  images.
- `MapTypeId.HYBRID` to displays a mixture of normal and satellite
  views.
- `MapTypeId.TERRAIN` to displays a physical map based on terrain
  information.

Furthermore, you can create custom map types by providing your own tile set.